EntityManager not injected after re-augment my Quarkus app
I'm defining an data access layer as an external jar containing the following dependencies
        <!-- SQL client for PostgreSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

In my app, I'm using the quarkus.package.jar.user-providers-directory=providers properties in my application.properties file as following:
quarkus.package.jar.user-providers-directory=providers
quarkus.package.jar.type=mutable-jar

and I copying my external library jar into the folder providers
I'm re-augmenting my app in order to inject the defining beans in my external library jar
java -jar -Dquarkus.launch.rebuild=true  target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar --debug

The issue that EntityManager still not injectible.
